# How to get 2133 speed out of my RAM

Tags: memory

I have an Asrock P67 Extreme4 Gen 3 motherboard and I just bought a pair of dual channel G Skill Trident X 8gb sticks that run at 2133. I popped them in and everything booted just fine, but my RAM speed still showed 1333 in Windows 10 Task Manager. I rebooted to my bios and set the memory profile to "Profile 2" that stated 2133 as the speed. This time it seemed to fail to boot a couple of times, then booted just fine, but speed showed 1333 still. Is there a way to get the RAM speed to work at 2133 with this motherboard?

Comment: According to comments on Newegg for that motherboard, multiple people had the same issue and they said setting it to 1866 was the highest they could go. Give that a try and see if it's stable at 1866.

Comment: I've read elsewhere that the speed reflected in the Task Manager for RAM isn't always true.  In my case, I have RAM set at 2400.  Windows Task Manager says its at 1600.  However, using [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) shows that my DRAM frequency is 1200 (which is correct since 1200 is half of 2400 -- [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_data_rate) can help explain this).  See what CPU-Z says perhaps?

Comment: Thanks so much for the insights. I'll try these things out when I get home in a couple of hours. I'll comment if something here worked/solved the question so you can post it and I can accept it as an answer.